# Order of Autowiring in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like Spring to inject Beans in a given order. I faced a strange issue with the code below. Both `setAuthenticationProvider()` and `configureAuthManager()` methods are injected in a random order. If `configureAuthManager()` is injected first, then during the login I get a NPE. Otherwise it works well.

So I want to force Spring to keep the order. I tried to annotate `setAuthenticationProvider` with `Order(1)` and the latter with `Order(2)` - did not help (why?). Then I also tried to to use `@DependsOn` annotation but it also didn't solve my problem.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    // @Order(1) - does not help
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider")
    public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        System.out.println("1");
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    // @Order(2) - does not help
    // @DependsOn("daoAuthenticationProvider") - does not help either
    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        System.out.println("2");
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Add the `AuthenticationProvider` as an argument to the `configureAuthManager` method next to the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` argument.

Comment: It still don't know how to keep the order but your suggestion solved my problem - big thanks! Would you like to post it as an answer so I could accept it or was it just too simple and I should delete that question completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of the bean creation shouldn't matter. If you need dependencies to be injected before you can call a method either

1. Use constructor based dependency injecetion
2. Add the argument to the method that needs it and use `@Autowired` (or `@Bean` if it creates a bean).

Either way Spring will be able to figure out in which order to create the beans to satisfy all the dependencies at the right time.